# How to show the diagonal of product of Hausdorff spaces is not in the product of its Borel-$\sigma$ algebras?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, with $|X| > \mathfrak{c}$. $\mathcal{B}(X)$, $\mathcal{B}(X \times X)$ are Borel-$\sigma$ Algebras on $X$ and $X\times X$ respectively. $\mathcal{B}(X)⊗\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the product of Borel Algebra of $X$.Let the diagonal of $X \times X$ be$$\Delta = \{(x,x):x \in X\}$$

Then how to show that $\Delta \notin \mathcal{B}(X)⊗\mathcal{B}(X)$

I ran into this claim in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/), and particularly in Gerald Edgar's answer in which $X$ is discrete(Is it necessary?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discreteness is not necessary: there is a link in one of the comments to [this page](http://david.efnet-math.org/?p=16), which has a proof of the following result:

> **Theorem (Nedoma’s Pathology):** Let $X$ be a measurable space with $|X|>2^{\aleph_0}$. Then the product algebra on $X^2$ does not contain the diagonal. In particular, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then the diagonal is a closed set in the product topology that is not contained in the product algebra.

The crucial lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $U\subseteq X^2$ be measurable. Then $U$ is the union of at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ boxes, sets of the form $A\times B$.

Once you have the lemma, the argument is easy: any box contained in the diagonal is a singleton.

Comment: Could you please give an address for the above lemma?

Comment: @ABB Here's a proof sketch: For any measurable set $U$, you only "use" countably many elements in the generating set to generate $U$. Therefore, $U$ is in a sub-$\sigma$-algebra generated by countably many measurable sets, say $A_1, A_2, ...$. For each $(x, y) \in X^2$, look at which of the $A_i$'s they are in, to get two subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. This gives a map $X^2 \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})^2$. The subsets of $X^2$ that are the preimage of subsets of $P(\mathbb{N})^2$ form a $\sigma$-algebra and contains each $A_i \times A_j$, so they are the desired boxes.

Comment: Full details are here : https://www.drmaciver.com/2006/04/journal-of-obscure-results-1-nedomas-pathology/

Comment: Nice argument. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidLui: For some reason I never saw **ABB**’s question, so many thanks for answering it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also get this as a simple corollary of the following result of general interest:

> **Theorem:** Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ be measurable spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a measurable function. Then the graph of $f$
>   is in $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$ if and only if there is a
>   countably generated $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{Y}$
>   such that $\{y\}\in\mathcal{C}$ for all $y\in f(X)$.

For a proof, see proposition 2.1. [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm110/fm110116.pdf). The result follows now using the fact that every countably generated $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a real-valued random variable. Just take $f$ to be the identity.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this implies the statement. If $f= Id$ then this theorem means that $\{(x,x)\} \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}$ iff $X \subseteq \sigma(A)$ for some countable $A\subset X$. But this latter statement is true which is the opposite of what we want?

Comment: You don't want $X$ in $\sigma(A)$, you want all singletons in $\sigma(A)$, and a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra cannot give rise to more than continuum many sets.