# What is the difference between $\mathcal B(E\times F)$ and $\mathcal B(E)\bigotimes\mathcal B(F)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> What is the difference between $\mathcal B(E\times F)$ and $\mathcal B(E)\bigotimes\mathcal B(F)$

I know the definition of $\mathcal B(E)\bigotimes\mathcal B(F)=\sigma\{A\times B:A\in\mathcal B(E), B\in\mathcal B(F)\}$

I heard that, $\mathcal B(E)\bigotimes\mathcal B(F)\subset\mathcal B(E\times F)$ with the following argument

$\pi_1:E\times F\to E$ and $\pi_2:E\times F\to F$ must be continuous, hence measurable. So if we endow these sets with the corresponding $\sigma$-algebras, we get for every $A\in\mathcal B(E),\ \pi_1^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal B(E\times F)$ and the same with the second projection, but what have we reached now, what has this to do with the definition above ?

Do you know an example, where the inclusion is strict, i.e. $\mathcal B(E)\bigotimes\mathcal B(F)\subsetneq\mathcal B(E\times F)$

I think i found it in the lecture notes, but the example is missing

http://imgim.com/img_20140404_143200.jpg (here the proposition, we need for the following lemma)

http://imgim.com/img_20140404_143214.jpg ( and the lemma, there's a typo in the lemma $f_2$ maps to $(F_2,\mathcal B_2)$)

Comment: Is that a tensor product. Sure looks like a tensor product.

Comment: @Marra it should be the symbol for the product $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/product-of-borel-sigma-algebras

Comment: @Byron Schmuland I don't see any concrete proof here.

Comment: @O.B.D.A. There is one: "Q1. Discrete spaces with cardinal > c ... then the diagonal is a Borel set, but not in the product sigma-algebra." -Gerald Edgar. To see that the diagonal is not productmeasurable, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340221/how-to-show-the-diagonal-of-product-of-hausdorff-spaces-is-not-in-the-product-of).