# Measurability of the diagonal in the product space

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space. Under which assumption on $(E,\mathcal E)$ can we show that $\Delta:=\left\{(x,x):x\in E\right\}\in\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E$? Note that [this doesn't hold in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340221/how-to-show-the-diagonal-of-product-of-hausdorff-spaces-is-not-in-the-product-of). Is it correct, for example, if $E$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$? A reference with a proof would be enough for me.

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer to the question you linked, my guess is that $\Delta\in\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{E}$ iff $|E|\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\{x\}\in\mathcal{E}$ for all $x\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

True for the Borel sigma algebra of any second countable space (in particular separable metric space).

Comment: Do you have a reference at hand?

Comment: It is easy to show that the product sigma field is nothing but the Borel sigma field of the product space under the assumption  of second countability. Since the Diagonal is a closed set its complement is open, hence Borel in the product, hence belongs to the product sigma filed.